# Not able to open and run on the simulator my .xcworkspace project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I recently acquired a new mac and I moved my project to it but although I can open files, I can't run them on the simulator and I can't run the .xcworkspace , this is what I see:[image]

and this is the folder
[image]
As you can see there are no files associated to my xcworkspace.
But when I open the xcodeproj file I can see everything
[image]
Can you please help?

Comment: Have you tried reinstall pods? Run `pod deintegrate && pod install`.

Comment: @krlbsk since I wrote the question my old mac crushed..I am moving everything to the new mac now, do I need to do what you suggested everytime I move a project to a new machine?Do I need to go to the folder containing my xcworkspace ,through the terminal and install the pods?

Comment: If you store pods in the repository, then you are not required to reinstall them again. The commands I sent you readd pods. Use it when you want to remove and add pods again, for example when something seems broken.

Comment: @krlbsk this might be a silly question, I just downloaded Xcode on my new machine and I moved all the files through a hard drive to it. on my new machine I can't run the xcworkspace since it seems that there are no files attached to it.But I can see the folders if I open the xcodeproj. Sorry for my incompetence but do you know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: It's may be because of different search paths, but I'm not sure. Try to reinstall pods and see what happens.

Comment: @krlbsk So do I need to access the folder containing the project workspace and run pod reintegrate and pod install afterward ?

Comment: @krlbsk Is my problem more clear, since when I do pod reintegrate I get the following error "-bash: pod: command not found" and when I do sudo pod reintegrate and I add my pass I get this error "sudo pod deintegrate
Password:
sudo: pod: command not found"

Comment: Have you install cocoapods? Haven't you made a typo in the command?

Comment: Read more about CocoaPods https://cocoapods.org/ and here is tutorial to get to know the basics https://www.raywenderlich.com/7076593-cocoapods-tutorial-for-swift-getting-started.

Comment: Just download your project to a new Mac using GitHub. I also transferred files from. my old computer lately and it seems as the most efficient way to prevent any troubles.

Comment: @krlbsk -Thank you so much for the information, I think I have a better understanding now. I deleted the xcworkspace and pods and I reinstalled the pods that I needed and everything works fine now. But do I need to do the same procedure for each of the versions or I need to access the folders containing the old workspaces and do the procedure that you suggested above?Is the intention of "pod deintegrate && pod install" to update the dependencies?

Comment: No, those commands should be used when you have some issues with current configuration. For updating dependencies you should call `pod update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go inside the project folder then type:

```
    pod repo update
    pod deintegrate && pod install
```

remember to open project from .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj